# Black box test cases for insertion procedure

Tags: c, sorting, testcase, black-box

```
insertion_procedure (int a[], int p [], int N)
{
    int i,j,k;
    for (i=0; i<=N; i++) p[i] = i;
    for (i=2; i<=N; i++)
    {
        k = p[i];
        j = 1;
        while (a[p[j-1]] > a[k]) {p[j] = p[j-1]; j--}
        p[j] = k;
    }
}
```

What would be few good test cases for this particular insertion procedure?

Comment: I'd start by writing a spec for the function. Preferably in comments right above it. Use the syntax of your most favorite comment extraction engine. (I'm using http://wwww.doxygen.org, if you haven't got one yet.)

Comment: If you want to write "black box" test cases the function code is not useful, a specification of the function with pre and post conditions is.  That's what "black box" means.

Answer (score 1):

If I read this function correctly any input with this property
a[0] > a[2] will seg fault

First loop through `for (i=2; i<=N; i++)`

Tracing the variables in my head.

1. `i = 2`
2. `k = p[i] == 2`
3. `j = 1`
4. `p[j-1] = p[0] == 0`
5. Because `a[0] > a[2]` while loop condition is true, therefore `j-- == 0`
6. Next evaulation of while condition will do: `while (a[p[-1] > k)` -> SEGFAULT

That might be a good test :-)

It doesn't look like there is any useful input that would make that while loop run more than once without a segfault so I'd say there is a logic error there

Answer (score 1):

**I would start with these**

- a negative number in a[]. What should the result be?
- a negative number in p[].
- a negative number N.
- an empty a array.
- an empty p array.
- N = 0

Looking at the implementation (I don't programm in c), I suspect some of these will AV.

In a nutshell, you should at least do a boundary analysis of your input parameters and device a test for each parameter with each value out of bound, on the boundary and inbound.

**Example**
If you have 1 parameter and determine the bounds are 0 and 10, it should result in 6 testcases. You should pass in -1, 0, 1, 9, 10 and 11.

**Further study**
As the ammount of parameters grows, it will quickly become impossible to test **all** combinations. This is where [all-pairs testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All-pairs_testing) would come in handy.